# Lua: gmatch, last occurence - greedy quantificator is extemely slow

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

Lua 5.2 (not jit). (And I know that my regex is probably inefficient, if you have a better one, I will appreciate it)

I'm trying to find the last occurrence of a string in the file. It looks something like this:

`2018-05-02 11-05-06|(some text)And code phrase is "code/xx-nn."`

I read the whole file and then I'm using following code:

```
local y, m, d, H, M, S, code = content:gmatch('.*\n(%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+) (%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+)|[^\n]+And code phrase is "code[/\\]([%a-]+)%."')()
```

If there is string somewhere in the file, Lua will quickly find it, but if there is not - it will take up to second to just dig through the text and return `nil`.

I wonder why. Is greedy quantificator that slow? Or my regex is wrong?

I tried to use `string.reverse()` on content and then just make a reversed regex:

```
local code, S, M, H, d, m, y = content:gmatch('"%.([%a-]+)[/\\]edoc" si esarhp edoc dnA[^\n]+|(%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+) (%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+)')()
```

And it works fast even if there is no string that I need in the file.

Comment: `local tm, code = content:match('^.*\n([^\n]+)And code phrase is "code[/\\]([%a-]+)%."'); local y, m, d, H, M, S = tm:match('^(%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+) (%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+)|')`

Comment: Your regex is slow because it successfully parses `(%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+) (%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+)|` for **every** line of file.

Comment: Since you are after the last occurrence, load the file line by line into an array and process the elements in reverse until the first match.